# Creating a non-autoincrement sort key

Tags: mysql, sorting, auto-increment

Currently I have 3 values that I need to sort, in the following order: gameDate, some-column-that-guarantees-insertion-order, team score.

Obviously, with the second sort param as a unique key, the 3rd sort param will be ignored. So, rather than sorting by, say, game result PK id, in the production app I created a "sort" column that stores a non-unique incremented value (see query result below), which then allows a

`SORT BY gameDate, sort, total DESC`

where sorting by total gives me the winning (or tie-ing) team first, so I don't have to

`if(teamA.total >= teamB.total) // show winner on left, loser on right`

in the application layer to generate the weekly games report.

So, in order to have my sorting cake, and not maintain an intermediary sort column, it appears that a datetime or timestamp could do the trick; however, the catch is that I need the sort on the insertion date non-uniquely (date value must be the same for both participant team result rows), otherwise, it's the same as sorting on game result PK id, the 3rd sort column will be ignored.

Why do I need to do this? Requirements are that the most recent game results should be displayed last on any given game date (which sort by gameDate, PK id does), and my own requirement is that the 3rd column sort on total is reachable (which again, is NOT possible with a unique-key-column as the 2nd sort param).

Probably even now this is clear as mud ;-)

**ORIGINAL**
I have a list of game results that need to be displayed in a report, sorted by game date, followed by a fixed sort order (i.e. cannot sort on game ID as the most recently displayed games must display last for each date in the report) and finally by winning team score.

In the current version of the app I'm using an int sort column, which, on game result submission, is queried for and then incremented by 1 for the db insert operation.  The end result is that I can run a query like:

```
SELECT id, gameID, gameDate, teamID, total, sort 
FROM games 
ORDER BY gameDate, sort, total desc

+----+--------+------------+--------+-------+------+
| id | gameID | gameDate   | teamID | total | sort |
+----+--------+------------+--------+-------+------+
|  1 |      3 | 2011-12-01 |    798 |     6 |  161 |
|  2 |      3 | 2011-12-01 |    106 |     3 |  161 |
|  3 |      4 | 2011-12-01 |     78 |     8 |  162 |
|  4 |      4 | 2011-12-01 |    106 |     7 |  162 |
|  5 |      5 | 2011-12-04 |    106 |     4 |  163 |
|  6 |      5 | 2011-12-04 |    167 |     3 |  163 |
+----+--------+------------+--------+-------+------+
```

However, I'd prefer to not deal with maintaining a sort column. Yes, I can sort by gameDate and then by game result id PK in the query, and determine winning team sort in the application layer, doing an `if(teamA.total >= teamB.total) ....`, but that is ugly as well ;-)

I'm thinking maybe a DateTime, or Timestamp (if that allows non-unique) might do the trick. Bit risky given that MySQL does not, as I recall, handle microseconds, so the problem of 2 different game results being submitted at the same time is a possiblity (which could cause the game report to display incorrectly).

Anyway, bottomline is that I need to find a way to sort by game date *and* preserve insertion order so I can get the last sort clause on team's score for the game (i.e. sort by winning team).

Ideas appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding why you need the sort column to begin with.  You can use a timestamp to store and maintain entry date and sort order, and your primary key can be (`gameID`, `teamID`)

Comment: Why you don't want to use auto-increment?

Comment: @Kamil because I need the final sort on winning team; if I sort by gameDate followed by PK of auto-increment of games table (there is an id column there, not shown in query), then it won't be possible to sort on team score

Comment: In that case you store the insertion date, either as a real timestamp (now()) or as an autoincremented sequence. Both are guaranteed to be (monotonously) increasing and thus unique.

Comment: updated to show pk auto-increment id column as well

Comment: @ajacian81 there is a PK, forgot to include in the query result. re: timestamp, well, that's what I suggested in my question? gameID is FK to composite schedule table where gameID is generated. I need to see if there are any concurrency issues with timestamp or datetime. Basically I need teamA, teamB records for a game to have the same insertion time, otherwise, sorting by gameDate, timestamp, total desc will not work (i.e. if insertion time is different for both rows)

Comment: @virtualeyes I dont understand. You should store/calculate score and then sort by that score...

Comment: @virtualeyes As far as I understand you want to insert a game score in two rows. And you also want to maintain the order of winning and losing team. If so insert 0 for losing team and 1 for winning team in column named _sort_ instead of identical values. I don't see a _gameDate_ column in data provided but I guess it is form a join with another table.

Comment: @Ertunç yes, gameDate is in separate composite schedule table. That is a better solution, 0 and 1 vs. maintaining a sort column. Of course nobody is grasping the fundamental problem that it is NOT possible to sort by gameDate, some-unique-key, some-other-column-that-will-never-be-sorted. Will update the question

Comment: @wildplasser, I already have insertion order guaranteed with game result PK id, that's not the problem (see updated question for details). If I take the moment-in-time route, it needs to be the same for both team game result rows, otherwise the 3rd sort param is not reachable -- basically I need, "sort by gameDate, semi-unique-key, total desc"

Comment: What is wrong with: `ORDER BY gameDate, game_id, total desc, team_id` ? (the final sort on team_id is only intended as a tie-breaker)

Comment: @virtualeyes Why that sort is not possible? It is not totally clear for me. What is the desired result? What is the query you will execute on this table you're trying to restructure? If you want to maintain the insertion order of data use timestamp. Generate it in the application, two different values for each game-team score. Do not store it in a datetime field if it loses precision. Store it inside varchar for example.

Comment: @wildplasser because we need for the most recently submitted game results to be displayed LAST; gameID is generated at time of schedule submission, and has nothing directly to do with game result insertion order. I need just that a tie-breaker for the 2nd sort param, and that is the semi-unique sort key I would like to replace

Comment: @Ertunç I need not 2 different values, but 2 SAME values for the 2nd sort param; if the values are different then the 3rd sort param is never reached

Comment: There is no thing as semi-unique. This means you need two columns. First one to indicate that 'this' two rows selected belong to same game. The second column to indicate the winner (The team with the higher score). So if sorting on id, gameid and score (I assume in each row above you store the value of score committed by that team) does not give you the result I have no other comments

Comment: @Ertunç what I am calling semi-unique is the sort pairing I have right now, I just don't want to maintain it.

Comment: @virtualeyes Completely different suggestion: If you want the last game available all the time, while inserting to this table (maybe this table is used for other purposes I dont konw), insert data into a table say called mostrecentscore (truncate this table everytime before you insert, so that always only two rows-or a sinle row for the most recent data exists).

Comment: @Ertunç yeah, trying to maintain less, not more ;-) I posted a possible solution, seems pretty close to what I need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

storing insertion as a DateTime seems the easier and more maintainable approach (vs. hacked sort column currently in place); the sort clause then becomes:

```
SORT BY gameDate, createDate, gameID, total DESC
```

Where createDate is non-unique, which means that subsequent sort columns are reachable. In this scenario even if 2 separate game results are submitted at the same time, it won't matter as gameID sort provides the gateway to the desired final sort, the winning team ;-)

So basically I can do in the application layer:

```
games.map(x=> dao.insert(x))
```

where each participant team in the game result has the same DateTime value for createDate column.

Should do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

Further discussion from my comment:

1) If you know that each game only has 2 teams, there's no need to normalize in this fashion. Something along the lines of:
gameID, team1ID, team1Total, team2ID, team2Total, tsPosted 
would probably be better.

Well 1) is enough for now. Was going to mention that you can join a table on itself and find the winner that way without requiring any logic on the application layer.

Comment: right, good luck creating aggregate reports with that kind of schema, no thanks ;-) The only non-normalized data is in the composite schedule table, where the game ID is generated, which does have team1, team2 on one row. Otherwise, game results table contains separate rows for each team result. With that I can very easily create straight forward queries for league standings, scoring leaders, etc. without littering queries with OR conditions